# WordPress ReAuth =1 Loop with wpCAS

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, capistrano, cas

The **wpCAS plugin** appears to be working: I have a **subdomain** on a website which contains the **WordPress** installation (i.e. `test.mywebsite.com`), and I'm running through a **WordPress GitHub Repo** along with **Capistrano** for actual deployment. This is important because, due to this setup, the content is within a subdirectory, i.e. `test.mywebsite.com/wp`. The result is that, in order to access the site's admin section, I have to input `test.mywebsite.com/wp/wp-admin` in my browser. Accessing the frontend website, however, only requires that I input `test.website.com`. Confusing enough?

I'm testing all of this with a **localhost MAMP server**. It should also be worth nothing that I have also redirected the IP of `test.mywebsite.com` to my local box via my Mac's `hosts` file, so everything is correctly taking place on the local box.

Now, here's the catch: I'm using the wpCAS plugin with a **RubyCAS server**. Everything works up until the actual login process.

wpCAS is designed to simply **re-direct the login page to my CAS login**, and then **match the credentials** typed into the CAS interface with those in WordPress's database. If there's a match, it (theoretically) would bring me to the admin page with my credentials logged in and working correctly.

As a result of this setup, my typing in `localhost/wp/wp-admin` takes me to `auth.mywebsite.com`, the CAS interface where I can input my credentials.

However, once I put my credentials into the CAS interface I'm instead hit with a **redirect loop** that looks like:

`wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fwp%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

and

`wp-admin/`

so around and around we go!

Any idea why this would happen and how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! Within the `wpcas.php` file inside of the `wpCAS` plugin folder, lines 85-123 detail the actual login function of **wpCAS**. **Lines 104** & **108** detail specifically on how wpCAS redirects you to the admin page:

**104**:

```
wp_redirect( preg_match( '/^http/', $_GET['redirect_to'] ) ? $_GET['redirect_to'] : site_url( $_GET['redirect_to'] ));
```

**108**:

```
wp_redirect( site_url( '/wp-admin/' ));
```

However, this results (for reasons unknown to me) in a redirect loop of ***[DOOM](http://nooooooooooooooo.com/)***. Thanks to [this tip](http://maisonbisson.com/projects/wpcas/comment-page-1/#comment-246162), however (many thanks to Mr. Luigi Balzano), I found a solution. Change the `wp_redirect` functions on these two lines to `wp_safe_redirect`, like so:

**104**:

```
wp_safe_redirect( preg_match( '/^http/', $_GET['redirect_to'] ) ? $_GET['redirect_to'] : site_url( $_GET['redirect_to'] ));
```

**108**:

```
wp_safe_redirect( site_url( '/wp-admin/' ));
```

This kicked me out of the redirect loop of ***[DOOM](http://nooooooooooooooo.com/)***.

The plugin, despite being two years old, still works beautifully with **WordPress** version 3.5.1 and below.

Hope this helps you wpCAS vagrants!

Comment: It's also worth noting that I also posted this question on the WordPress Answers StackExchange. I have also answered the question there, so if this is an unnecessary duplication, you folks are alright to remove this. I'm leaving it, as it may help StackOverflow users who are not aware of WordPress Answers like I was.